# How can I keep a backend module ('manual_scaling') running indefinitely?

Tags: google-app-engine, module

I have defined a route in a backend module this way

```
(r'/_ah/start', 'ConversionTaskQueueWorker'),
```

My backend module is terminated like so:

[image]

But if I put a log statement in

```
class ConversionTaskQueueWorker(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        """Indefinitely fetch tasks and update the datastore."""
        q = taskqueue.Queue(TASK_QUEUE_NAME)
        while True:
            LOG.info('Keeping it alive')
            ...
```

It stays up and running

[image]

Why it is so?

I don't want to flood my log with this message. Is there any alternative way to keep the backend module running?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If it's just processing tasks from the queue, you should let GAE manage it depending on the load.

Comment: To run a 24x7 job to monitor a pull queue